# E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-industrial-core

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm trying to control an ABB IRB120 with ROS. For that matter, I want to install ROS-industrial.

I am following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install but when executing "sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-industrial-core", the message "E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-industrial-core" appears. It looks like the industrial core packages are not supported for ROS Melodic.

Will I have to install this package from a not-fully-supported source? or something like that? I am new to ROS. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using the ROS Melodic Morenia distribution with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Kind regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316537/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-industrial-core/) by [AlexCC](https://answers.ros.org/users/40185/alexcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`industrial_core` (and all the packages in that repository) were released into Melodic and with the [sync out](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-melodic-2019-03-04/8120) are now available to install with `apt` on supported OS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexCC](https://answers.ros.org/users/40185/alexcc/) on 2019-03-04**:
wow! those are great news! thank you for the answer.
After doing some readings I have finally managed to get it going, working with the RViz and connecting to the RobotStudio environment.

**Comment by [ahmed ali 95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53435/ahmed-ali-95/) on 2020-04-13**:
@AlexCC, could you please guide that how did you install ROS-industrial into ROS melodic with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I am new to ROS? please help, thanks.

**Comment by [AlexCC](https://answers.ros.org/users/40185/alexcc/) on 2020-04-14**:
Hi ahmed ali! of course. I know how frustrating it was for me as a ROS Beginner, to have these things installed and correctly running. I managed to document all the steps I followed. Here is the document that will help you on this task.
[my document on how to install ROS industrial into ROS Melodic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13VYak7t6LKvwW5ZcnZyLdu63RvDu3W40)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-14**:
+100 for sharing your document, but as I wrote in my answer, `sudo apt install ros-melodic-industrial-core` should just work, as the package has been released. Building from source is not necessary.

See [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=industrial_core](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=industrial_core).

Same for ABB. Only `abb_experimental` needs to be built from source, as it is an experimental repository and does not get released.

**Comment by [AlexCC](https://answers.ros.org/users/40185/alexcc/) on 2020-04-14**:
Yes! I forgot to mention that, ahmed ali... However that is also included in the document. There is an "UPDATE" part which explains about this. Please read the whole document before installing something.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-14**:\

> There is an "UPDATE" part which explains about this

you may want to move that update to the start of the document. It's "hidden" somewhere quite far down. Users which are used to copy-paste their way through instructions will have executed about 60% of the instructions before they get to that update.

**Comment by [AlexCC](https://answers.ros.org/users/40185/alexcc/) on 2020-04-14**:
Yes, gvdhoorn  you are all right.. This is the new document updated. [UPDATED document on how to install ROS industrial with ROS Melodic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13VYak7t6LKvwW5ZcnZyLdu63RvDu3W40)

**Comment by [ahmed ali 95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53435/ahmed-ali-95/) on 2020-04-18**:
@AlexCC, thank you very much dear for sharing the detailed document. It helped a lot
and @gvdhoorn, thank you for the guidance